# Does selling exploration data increase reputation?

Tags: elite-dangerous

When exploring planets and returning to populated space does the exploration data increase reputation in the station you sell it too?   And if so is there an increase whether it is a normal scan or detailed scan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what I've learned while researching how to boost a minor faction's influence, and some reasonable assumptions...

I believe that selling exploration data increases your reputation with the minor faction that owns that station, and also boosts that minor faction's influence. I believe the amount it boosts your reputation (and their influence) will be based on the amount they pay for that exploration data. Since a detailed scan pays more, that will boost reputation and influence more.

For influence boosting, it's believed that the influence boost maxes out at about 10MCr per day per minor faction. It's likely that the same limit applies to boosting your reputation with them. If you're looking to boost your reputation with a single minor faction, it might be best to sell them 10MCr per day until you're done. If you're looking to boost your reputation with a major faction (Federation, Empire, Alliance), you might want to sell your exploration data 10MCr at a time to different minor factions allied to that major faction.

Note that exactly how reputation and influence work has changed in prior updates, and could change again. These changes could be in a server-side patch that you aren't even aware of. Trying to get too detailed with exactly how reputation and influence work can be pretty tricky because of this.

Comment: Selling data *definitely* boosts your rank with the local minor faction. I've come back from some long outings and gotten notifications of rank increases after turning in to UC.